# getMeasuredHeight() and width returning 0 after measure()

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm really confused with this whole measuring thing that android does for layouts. Basically, I want to get the actual computed height and width of a view when it has been laid out BEFORE it gets laid out. I need to get the computed height and width because I have a hidden `LinearLayout` that I want to animate when opening using viewpropertyanimator. I need to supply the target width (which is the computed width) to the animator before it animates it. The width of this layout is dynamic because it relies on its `android:weight` parameter for the width, so I can't give a static value.

Here's my activity class:

```
package com.example.testproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class TestActivity extends Activity
    {

    private LinearLayout gmailListContainer, yahooMailListContainer, windowsLiveListContainer;
    private LinearLayout emailMessageContainer;

    private Display display;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        gmailListContainer = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.email_activity_gmail_layout);
        yahooMailListContainer = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.email_activity_yahoo_mail_layout);
        windowsLiveListContainer = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.email_activity_windows_live_layout);
        emailMessageContainer = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.email_activity_email_content_layout);

        gmailListContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        yahooMailListContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        windowsLiveListContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        emailMessageContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        setMeasuredDimensions();
        }

    private void setMeasuredDimensions()
        {
        View v = this.findViewById(R.id.email_activity_layout);
        v.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
        Log.v("EmailActivity", v.getMeasuredHeight() + ", " +v.getMeasuredWidth());
        }

    private void setWeight(LinearLayout container, float weight)
        {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();
        params.weight = weight;
        container.setLayoutParams(params);
        container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
```

Here's the relevant layout resource:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/email_activity_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_activity_gmail_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_activity_yahoo_mail_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_activity_windows_live_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_activity_email_content_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the below method to your Activity and call your method from it.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
      setMeasuredDimensions();
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

In onCreate() you can't assure that your view is drawn. It might take some time. But this above method gets called only when the view is drawn completely. So YOu should be able to get the width and height exactly here.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. Here's an edited one:

Hey there! I tried your solution, and it works, however when i call `v.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());` again, the values return to being 0. I've modified my code to log the height and width first, fire a measure command on the view again supplying the display's height and width, and logged height and width again. On the first log, the correct values are returned. On the second log, the values have been reset to 0. Why is that?

Comment: Did you check what your Display's width and height was? Maybe it is 0 itself

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not 0. Also, correct me if i'm wrong, but this approach asumes that the views have been drawn already. What I'm trying to find is a way to **1.** Set up the inner linear layouts such that the first 3 have weight=1 and the 4th has weight=0 **2.** Force layout, measure or something so that I can get computed height and weight for each in this mode **3.** Set up the layouts so that 2 of the first 3 layouts have weight=0 and 1 with weight=1, and the 4th has weight=2 **4.** get width and height for each in this 2nd mode **5.** Revert weights and only then will I draw the views

Comment: This looks to be huge. Probably you should ask it as a separate question so that someone could help you.